# MongoDB vs Columnar

Tags: mongodb

Is MongoDB a good fit when there are several combinations of columns used for querying , thus creating indexes on all of the columns is not feasible? How does MongoDB performs when, say, you have no index on the column and you have millions of entries for that column?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no index, a table scan is performed, as with any database system.

If the documents are in memory this will still be relatively fast but still take a given amount of time based on the number of documents in the collection as the database must look at each one. O(n)

Is the problem that you have a small set of varying keys per document or a large numer of keys that every document must have?

Column oriented datastores must store a large amount of columns to model varying attributes but mongodb is more flexible because of the document data model.

If you have documents that have a small number of varying attributes (out of a large set of attributes), this is indexable and will be O(logn).

Your documents would look like this:

```
{ 
  "name":"some name", 
  "attrs":[ 
    {"n":"subject","v":"the subject"}, 
    {"n":"description","v":"Some amazing description"}, 
    {"n":"comments","v":"Comments on this thing"}, 
  ] 
}
```

Be indexible like this:

```
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({"attrs.n":1, "attrs.v":1})
```

and be queryable like this:

```
db.mycollection.find({attrs: {$elemMatch: {n: "subject", v: "the subject"}}})
```

Comment: What I have is a STAR schema. I could denormalize this and store in columnar db which works great. I have same number of attributes for each document(row). What I want is the ability to do TOP N type of queries. I know there is some work going on in the new version (2.2 I think - aggregation), so, I would be able to do the TOP N, however, I was not sure if the performance for every attribute would be good enough or not as I can not create index on each and every attribute. I suspect MongoDB is not the solution for my problem but wanted to see if I am missing something!

Comment: Could you update your question with a concrete example of the sort of thing you want to do? (data and queries) I agree that indexing everything is out of the question but maybe there is another way to model the data?

Comment: Before I went any further in the direction of testing MongoDB with a large volume of data (and with different queries), I realized that there is no compression in MongoDB and that's a big bottleneck for me.